# Reducible polynomial over Q

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

Suppose that $f(x) = x^4 + a \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ is reducible over $\mathbb{Q}$ with $|a| > 1$, how can I see that then $|a|$ must be a square in $\mathbb{Z}$?

Not sure if there is any straightforward way here?

Comment: Please read [this post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9960) and the others there for information on writing a good question for this site. In particular, people will be more willing to help if you [edit] your question to include some motivation, and an explanation of your own attempts.

Comment: It also follows from [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2240197/fx-x4ax2b-in-mathbbzx-is-irreducible-iff-alpha-2-alpha-pm-bet).

Comment: @DietrichBurde I don't see why it follows from that post. Could you explain?

Comment: $x^4+ax^2+b$ reduces to $x^4+b$ for $a=0$. Then the post just says the same. So $x^4+b$ is irreducible if and only if the square of the roots, etc. is not in $\Bbb Q$. But this just amounts to saying that $-b$ is not a square.